# Filter a Polymorphic Table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Basically i've a polymorphic table that is as follows:

```
Polytable
--------

id
type
polyable_type
polyable_id
```

And the woly `Eloquent` polymorphic class is as follows:

```
class poly extends Eloquent {
     .... //eloquent attributes and stuff

     public function polyable()
     {
         return $this->morphTo();
     }
}
```

And the woly `Eloquent` standard class is as follows:

```
class woly extends Eloquent{
    ... //skipped most eloquent stuff

    public function poly()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('poly','polyable');
    }
    public function polyTypeOne()
    {
        return $this->poly()->where('type','=','1')->get();
    }
}
```

Now, i want `woly`'s polymorphic relationship `poly()` to return only items where `type` column in Polytable is `1`.

So far i've hit into the database performance issue, with the function `polyTypeOne()`

**Example of Using polyTypeOne function**

```
$wollies = woly::all();
foreach($wollies as $w)
{
    $w->polyTypeOne = $w->polyTypeOne();
}
```

What is the best way to perform such a function?

Comment: What performance issues and where's the code you execute?

Comment: Simply put, i cannot use `woly::with('polyTypeOne')->all()` for eager loading, given that it is not a relationship function.

Comment: Well, this piece can't work because 1 `all` is static method of the model, 2 `polyTypeOne` is not a relation. But remove `get()` from it and it will work as expected. Anyway, no performance issues so far, unless you refer to not being able to use eager loading..

Comment: Yup, wanted a solution, where i could use eager loading, while at the same time filtering the polymorphic relationship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public function polyTypeOne()
{
    return $this->poly()->where('type','=','1');
}

// usage
$wollies = Woly::with('polyTypeOne')->get();

// pretty much the same as:
$wollies = Woly::with(['poly' => function ($q) {
  $q->where('type', 1);
}])->get();
```

Comment: Can't believe it works. U actually learn new stuff from eloquent everyday.. Thanks man.